# SetupDiGetClassDescription returns FALSE, sets error 0xE0000206

Tags: setupapi

I've been playing with the SetupApi on Windows 2003 over the last couple of days, and I'm seeing a bunch of errors I'm not expecting. For example, if I pass `GUID_NULL` to `SetupDiGetClassDescription`, it returns FALSE and `GetLastError()` returns `0xE0000206`.

The GUID_NULL came from `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo`; I'm not doing this deliberately.

I've also seen error `0xE0000209`. Where are these "0xE" error values declared, defined or documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that they're in `SetupAPI.h`, but disguised.

`0xE0000206` is `ERROR_INVALID_CLASS`:

```
#define ERROR_INVALID_CLASS (APPLICATION_ERROR_MASK|ERROR_SEVERITY_ERROR|0x206)
```

...and `0xE0000209` is `ERROR_INVALID_REG_PROPERTY`:

```
#define ERROR_INVALID_REG_PROPERTY (APPLICATION_ERROR_MASK|ERROR_SEVERITY_ERROR|0x209)
```

(and, in WinNT.h)...

```
#define APPLICATION_ERROR_MASK       0x20000000
#define ERROR_SEVERITY_ERROR         0xC0000000
```

`0xC | 0x2` is `0xE`.